Is there anyway to decode program account change that I don’t know the struct?
I’m trying to decode update that I got from the call of “connection.onProgramAcccountChange” but I don’t know the struct of possible outcome, is there anyway to get the struct or decode it somehow ?
Thanks.

Since account data is just bytes, if you don't have some sort of schema definition, either through an IDL or a client library, you won't be able to interpret the bytes.
If you ask for jsonParsed encoding, then the RPC server will parse accounts owned by a few programs in an easy-to-digest format.
